# How to get auth state in Reactjs using Expressjs and Passportjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project that use Reactjs for front-end and Expressjs and Passportjs for server side.
The user information will be stored in cookie-session middleware in server side whenever he/she logged in. But every time the user opens the website, the react app will have to fetch user data by sending a http request to the server side and wait for it to response. This sometimes take some seconds or even longer when the connection is poor.
Is there any way to get user's auth state immediately? Thank in advanced!

Comment: Can you show where you are sending `http` request to `fetch user `

Comment: @Aaqib In the App.js for App component, I call this.props.fetchUser(); in the componentWillMount(). This will send a http request to the server side to ask for the user infor stored in cookie of the browser